# How can i print "_" for 1 second straight?

Tags: javascript, string, settimeout

I want to print out the underscore until 1 second, where it will then print out a " ". After 10 seconds, it will stop. But it times out on me. Pls tell me whats wrong or if what i am trying to achieve is impossible.

Code:

```
  var buttonpress = true;
  while(buttonpress === true){
    setTimeout(function(){buttonpress = false;},10000);
    document.write("_");
    setInterval(function(){document.write(" ");},1000);
  }
```

I have even tried this :

```
setInterval(function(){document.write("_");},100);
```

Comment: So you want a non-specific number of underscores, just however many the CPU can manage within one second, or...? Don't use `document.write()` with timers (or at all, if you can avoid it).

Comment: When `document.write` is used after the page has been parsed, it opens a new document, and wipes out all the previous content.

Comment: yes i do want just however many the CPU can manage within one second. thx. what should i use instead of document.write then?

Comment: You would set `document.write = function(text) { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text)); }` as a quick fix for the issues with `document.write()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.write()` after the page has loaded results in the browser opening a new document, overwriting the original one. So don't use `document.write()` with timers. (Or at all, if you can avoid it, which in 99% of cases you can.)

Here's the first way that came to mind that doesn't need `document.write()`:

```js
function doStuff() {  
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  
  var underscoreInterval = setInterval(function() {
    output.innerHTML += "_";
  }, 20); // delay of 20 for demo, could be reduced to 5 (or 0 - see note below)

  var spaceInterval = setInterval(function() {
    output.innerHTML += " ";
  }, 1000);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(underscoreInterval);
    clearInterval(spaceInterval);
  }, 10000);  
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
```

```html
<button>Start</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

That is, add an element to the html for the output, and add to it by updating its `.innerHTML`. Use `setInterval()` twice, once with a small delay to output underscores, and once with a one-second delay to output the spaces. Then use `setTimeout()` to cancel the intervals after ten seconds.

For the short delay I'm using 20ms for my demo so that it is easier to see what's happening when it runs, but you could reduce that to 5ms - you *could* specify 0ms, but in practice there's no point specifying less than 5ms because browsers round this argument up to 5ms.

If you want to be sure each line of underscores is the same length you'd maybe use just a single `setInterval()` with a counter.

Comment: Since `setInterval` is asynchronous, giving it a time interval of 0 ms wouldn't really hurt anything, since it would only execute when the CPU has time.

Comment: @4castle - True, although in practice values less than 5ms get rounded up to 5ms. I've aded a note about that in my answer.